# Error occur after changing firebase project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a little app with authentication and simple crud methods. I decided to change my app-connected firebase project to another new project. before I change the firebase project app was worked fine. but after change it, the authentication part works fine, but when I go to retrieve some data it shows the following error.

```
D/FirebaseAuth(20666): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth(20666): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
```

before I change the firebase project app was working fine.
I add JSON file correctly
are there any changes to do after change firebase project
please help me this situation is so hard.

it shows the following error too. Problem is app was work fine I am 100% these problems occur after change firebase project

[image]

Comment: Did you update the `google-services.json` file..after changing the project..!?

Comment: yes I did. delete the old one and replaced new one

Comment: try `flutter clean` and if you're using git make sure you're i the correct branch with the latest commits the run your project

Comment: i think this error is not in my code. flutter clean not working